# How can I get the filename in this json?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "data": {},
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-cache, private",
        "connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=15808735-9_cedula_frente_19-03-2019.pdf",
        "content-length": "147417",
        "content-type": "application/pdf",
        "date": "Wed, 04 Aug 2021 17:32:13 GMT",
        "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100",
        "server": "Apache"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "/documentation/download/131",
        "method": "get",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "timeout": 0,
        "responseType": "arraybuffer",
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

I wonder how can I get the filename in this json? I mean how can I get `filename=15808735-9_cedula_frente_19-03-2019.pdf` from this json?

Thanks

Comment: After parsing the JS, you can access the property with js dot/square bracket notation.

Comment: And you can use `split()` or a regexp to get the part after `;`.